# How can I solve this context=null problem in AndroidStudio Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new in android developing and I'm having issues when developing this Activity which basically compares faces.
The problem comes when I try to access "context" to capture my screen and save it in internal storage, I don't know how not to make `context=null` and actually be related with the Activity.

I know this has to be really simple but I can't find a solution. This is the code I have so far:

```
@ExperimentalGetImage public class Processor extends VisionBaseProcessor<List<Face>> {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    private static Bitmap bitmap;



    private boolean mDetectadoEncontrado = false;



    public Processor(Context context, FaceDetector detector, Interpreter faceNetModelInterpreter, ImageProcessor faceNetImageProcessor, Overlay graphicOverlay, FaceRecognitionCallback callback) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.detector = detector;
        this.faceNetModelInterpreter = faceNetModelInterpreter;
        this.faceNetImageProcessor = faceNetImageProcessor;
        this.graphicOverlay = graphicOverlay;
        this.callback = callback;
    }



    class Person {
        public String name;
        public float[] faceVector;

        public Person(String name, float[] faceVector) {
            this.name = name;
            this.faceVector = faceVector;
        }
    }

    public interface FaceRecognitionCallback {
        void onFaceRecognised(Face face, float probability, String name);
        void onFaceDetected(Face face, Bitmap faceBitmap, float[] vector);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "FaceRecognitionProcessor";

    // Input image size for our facenet model
    private static final int FACENET_INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = 112;

    private Context context;
    private final FaceDetector detector;
    private final Interpreter faceNetModelInterpreter;
    private final ImageProcessor faceNetImageProcessor;
    private final Overlay graphicOverlay;
    private final FaceRecognitionCallback callback;

    public RecFacialAct activity;

    List<Person> recognisedFaceList = new ArrayList();

    public Processor(Interpreter faceNetModelInterpreter,
                                    Overlay graphicOverlay,
                                    FaceRecognitionCallback callback) {
        super();
        this.callback = callback;
        this.graphicOverlay = graphicOverlay;
        // initialize processors
        this.faceNetModelInterpreter = faceNetModelInterpreter;
        faceNetImageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeOp(FACENET_INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, FACENET_INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                .add(new NormalizeOp(0f, 255f))
                .build();

        FaceDetectorOptions faceDetectorOptions = new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
                .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_NONE)
                // to ensure we don't count and analyse same person again
                .enableTracking()
                .build();
        detector = FaceDetection.getClient(faceDetectorOptions);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @OptIn(markerClass = ExperimentalGetImage.class)
    public Task<List<Face>> detectInImage(ImageProxy imageProxy, Bitmap bitmap, int rotationDegrees) {
        InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(imageProxy.getImage(), rotationDegrees);
        int rotation = rotationDegrees;


        boolean reverseDimens = rotation == 90 || rotation == 270;
        int width;
        int height;
        if (reverseDimens) {
            width = imageProxy.getHeight();
            height =  imageProxy.getWidth();
        } else {
            width = imageProxy.getWidth();
            height = imageProxy.getHeight();
        }

        return detector.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Face> faces) {
                        graphicOverlay.clear();
                        for (Face face : faces) {
                            FaceGraphic faceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(graphicOverlay, face, false, width, height);
                            Log.d(TAG, "face found, id: " + face.getTrackingId());

                            Bitmap faceBitmap = cropToBBox(bitmap, face.getBoundingBox(), rotation);

                            if (faceBitmap == null) {
                                Log.d("GraphicOverlay", "Face bitmap null");
                                return;
                            }

                            TensorImage tensorImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(faceBitmap);
                            ByteBuffer faceNetByteBuffer = faceNetImageProcessor.process(tensorImage).getBuffer();
                            float[][] faceOutputArray = new float[1][192];
                            faceNetModelInterpreter.run(faceNetByteBuffer, faceOutputArray);

                            Log.d(TAG, "output array: " + Arrays.deepToString(faceOutputArray));

                            if (callback != null) {
                                callback.onFaceDetected(face, faceBitmap, faceOutputArray[0]);
                                if (callback != null) {
                                    callback.onFaceDetected(face, faceBitmap, faceOutputArray[0]);

                                    // Hacer una consulta a la colección "caras"
                                    db.collection("caras").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = task.getResult().getDocuments();
                                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
                                                    String name = document.getString("name");
                                                    List<Double> vector = (List<Double>) document.get("vector");
                                                    float[] faceVector = new float[vector.size()];

                                                    RecFacialAct.recognizeFace(faceOutputArray[0]);

                                                    LogcatHelper logcatHelper = new LogcatHelper("RecFacialAct", "detectado", new LogcatHelper.LogcatListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onMatchFound(String line) {
                                                            mDetectadoEncontrado = true;


                                                            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

                                                            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

                                                            Point size = new Point();
                                                            display.getSize(size);
                                                            int width = (int) size.x;
                                                            int height = (int) size.y;
                                                            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                                                            int[] pixelBuffer = new int[width * height];
                                                            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

                                                            PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener listener = new PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onPixelCopyFinished(int copyResult) {
                                                                    if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                                                                        // La copia se realizó correctamente, haz lo que quieras con el bitmap
                                                                        saveBitmapToInternalStorage(bitmap);
                                                                        Log.d("Captura", "Captura guardada");
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        // La copia falló, maneja el error
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            };
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                                    logcatHelper.start();


                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }

                            graphicOverlay.add(faceGraphic);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // intentionally left empty
                    }
                });
    }

    private void saveBitmapToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File directory = context.getDir("screenshots", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File file = new File(directory, "screenshot.png");

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private Pair<String, Float> findNearestFace(float[] vector) {

        Pair<String, Float> ret = null;
        for (Person person : recognisedFaceList) {
            final String name = person.name;
            final float[] knownVector = person.faceVector;

            float distance = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
                float diff = vector[i] - knownVector[i];
                distance += diff*diff;
            }
            distance = (float) Math.sqrt(distance);
            if (ret == null || distance < ret.second) {
                ret = new Pair<>(name, distance);
            }
        }

        return ret;

    }

    public void stop() {
        detector.close();
    }

    private Bitmap cropToBBox(Bitmap image, Rect boundingBox, int rotation) {
        int shift = 0;
        if (rotation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
        if (boundingBox.top >= 0 && boundingBox.bottom <= image.getWidth()
                && boundingBox.top + boundingBox.height() <= image.getHeight()
                && boundingBox.left >= 0
                && boundingBox.left + boundingBox.width() <= image.getWidth()) {
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    image,
                    boundingBox.left,
                    boundingBox.top + shift,
                    boundingBox.width(),
                    boundingBox.height()
            );
        } else return null;
    }

    // Register a name against the vector
    public void registerFace(Editable input, float[] tempVector) {
        recognisedFaceList.add(new Person(input.toString(), tempVector));
    }
```

In theory I was expecting my Activity to take an screenshot, however i end up getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: es.upsa.mjb, PID: 6059
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at es.upsa.mjb.helper.Processor$2$1$1.onMatchFound(Processor.java:195)
        at es.upsa.mjb.LogcatHelper$1.lambda$run$0$es-upsa-mjb-LogcatHelper$1(LogcatHelper.java:39)
        at es.upsa.mjb.LogcatHelper$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```